# PHP index not connected to Model class

Tags: php

I'm trying to test it using a simple Example I wrote but the Browser always says :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Model' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvcFirst\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvcFirst\index.php on line 9

I've searched in internet but didn't found the reason for that.
Here is my Code:

1. Model Class :

   ```
   <?php

   class Model
   {
       public $string;
       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->string="MVC and PHP are awesome!";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Controller Class :

   ```
   <?php
   class Controller
   {
       private $model;
       public function __construct($model)
       {
           $this->model=$model;
       }
   }
   ```
3. View Class :

   ```
   <?php
   class View
   {
       private $controller;
       private $model;
       public function __construct($controller,$model)
       {
           $this->controller=$controller;
           $this->model=$model;
       }
       public  function output(){
           return "<p>".$this->model->string."</p>";
        }
   }
   ```
4. index.php :

   ```
   <?php

   try {
       $model = new Model();
       $controller = new Controller($model);
       $view = new View($controller, $model);
       echo $view->output();
   }catch (Exception $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();

   }
   ?>
   ```

   **with any suggestion i'll be Thankful.**

Comment: Learn about autoloaders

Comment: Is this a custom made MVC structure ?

Comment: In PHP you need to include the files you need. You don't seem to be doing this. A common (modern) pattern is using autoloading. This is a function that runs when PHP encounters a class it can not find. It will attempt to load the class using the namespace and the name of the class. This does the includes "magically" and automatically for you.

Comment: can you show your folder structure?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay nope its as normal structure im just trying to test it cuz im new for MVC idea.

Comment: You need to autoload your classes if you want to go the proper OOP direction or you can just include them like @OptimusCrime has suggested.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC. Go an read what "autoloader" in PHP is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you need to include the external files you wish to use. One way to do this is to use the function `include_once` and specify each file you want to include in your code.

Assuming your files are named `model.php`, `controller.php` and `view.php`, you need to put this right after the opening php tag in your `index.php` file:

```
include_once './model.php';
include_once './controller.php';
include_once './view.php';
```

Another way is to apply autoloading. Autoloading is done when PHP encounters a class it has not yet seen, and a class that is not yet loaded. The autoloading is done using the function [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). The official docs contains a very simple illustrative code for how it works:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});
```

Comment: It works! like Magic lol realy thx man.
I didnt knew about that i must before include them , i thought i didnt need it cuz there were Classes not a php file.

Comment: @SamBoHamdan You should really read up on autoloading as it makes this entire process a lot easier to handle. Otherwise you will spend the end of your days including files. This will also break as soon as you move files around etc. Autoloading is much easier to manage.

Comment: Done, Vote up  :)